# Android - How to create a view with rounded corners and a tiled image background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-image, android-shapedrawable

I'm trying to create a view in `Android` that has rounded corners and also uses a tiled image background (and which appears on top of another view with a tiled background).

I can create a shape drawable for the corners and a bitmap drawable for the tiled image, but I can't see how I can apply them both the same view.

Some things I've attempted:

- Nesting the view with the tiled background inside a view with rounded corners - doesn't work, the tiled background just appears on top with square corners
- Paint over the corners of the view with rounded corners - this doesn't work because of the tiled background of the view below (otherwise would work fine)

Comment: Do you want to implement tiled background with round corners?

Comment: Not exactly what you want but this shows how to implement rounded corners: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/rounded-corners-mapview/

Comment: @teoREtik, yes that's pretty much what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Blundell, thanks for that link. I see what they're doing here - essentially just painting round black corners on top of the view. That would work _except_ in my case I'm trying to place the view on top of another tiled-background view, so the corners actually need to be cut off, rather than just painted over.

Comment: Does painting over them not give the illusion that they have been cut off?

Comment: @Blundel, no because you can only paint over the corners with a solid colour, but the background of the view _under_ the view I'm trying to create also has a tiled image background...

Comment: @Mick hmm bit more complex than I thought, have you looked at Canvas.drawArc()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your custom View should define its drawing region with a Path. You could then draw the Path with a paint and shader doing what you want (fill and tile).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF6Ad4GYjRU) which contains a way to do it without using `clipPath` which is not supported with hardware acceleration.